# how to add clone git to my own created repo in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

How to take the project from one repo (where I've been given developer rights by some other person who is the master) to my own created repo (where I'm the master). I'm able to use both CMD and webstorm IDE for accessing GIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action you want to perform is called 'fork' in the context of source code management (e.g git). Quoting https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/fork-project.html:

> A fork is a copy of an original repository that you put in another namespace where you can experiment and apply changes that you can later decide whether or not to share, without affecting the original project.

To fork a project in GitLab, you just have to click on the 'fork' button on the project's main page.

[image: Forking a project in GitLab]

You can read detailed steps on https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/forking_workflow.html#creating-a-fork